# I have a html page with form.I want to write it to a file and then use the file content for my app

Tags: php, android, html, android-studio

I have a html page and an android app both are separate, but on the same server.So I want to get the input field values from the form and put it in a text file.And use these value from text file for processing.
For example :
in form, input would be 6(any number). So I want to create 6 different buttons and some text inputs which will be the name of buttons.
How should I go about this using php ?Thanks

> [0307/175819.921:ERROR:file_io_win.cc(163)] CreateFile C:\Program Files (x86)\settings.dat: Access is denied. (0x5)
>   [0307/175819.924:ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(84)] TransactNamedPipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)
>   [0307/175819.927:ERROR:file_io_win.cc(163)] CreateFile C:\Program Files (x86)\settings.dat: Access is denied. (0x5)
>   [0307/175820.050:ERROR:crashpad_client_win.cc(660)] crash server failed to launch, no dump captured

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error while using latest AngularJS version. But, When I tried with little older version, the issue has been resolved.

Below does not work for me.

```
<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

But, this worked.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"><script>
```